# How to create an optional section in my template that will render near the bottom

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a master layout in my playframework application that is like:

```
@(title: String = "Home")(content: Html)

<html>
<body>
..

@content
..

<script type="text/javascript">

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Now in a typical page that uses the above layout I have:

```
@layouts.master(title = "About Us") {

<h1>About us</h1>
..

}
```

Now I want to be able to create a write javascript in my view page, and have it injected into the master layout inside of the javascript `<script>...</script>` tags.

Note:  I want this to be optional.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly modify your master layout so it can take some JavaScript as a parameter.

```
@(title: String = "Home", scripts: Html = Html(""))(content: Html)

<html>
<body>
..

@content
..

<script type="text/javascript">
@scripts
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

By providing a default value for this parameter you make it optional. Next you can define a sample script in one of your views and pass it to the template as follows:

```
@scripts = {
    alert('This is the passed script!');
}

@layouts.master(title = "About Us", scripts) {

<h1>About us</h1>
..

}
```

This technique is [documented](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaTemplateUseCases) in the section **moreScripts and moreStyles equivalents**.